# an image mapped button firing a javascript alert

Tags: javascript, image, maps

I have a large image that contains a button graphic.  I don't want the whole image to be clickable, just the button graphic.

When the user clicks the button, a javascript alert message must fire.  Can this be done using javascript and an image map?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure, alternately you could just build a div that is the same size as the image and position a clickable area inside of it:

```
<div style="background: url(path/to/image.jpg); height: 200px; padding: 50px 0pt 0pt 50px;">
  <a onClick="alert('Button Clicked!');" href="#">
    <div style="height: 20px; width: 30px;"></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Trey.  I'm getting an error "unterminated string constant" could you tell me what that means?  here is my code:                                                            <div class="hc_left_pic"><a onClick="alert('Button Clicked!);" href="#">
    <div class="addcart"><img src="images/addcart.jpg" /></div>
  </a></div>  If put the button as a background image it disappeared.  I tried using z-index:100, but that didn't work.  so i appended the image within the inner div.    Sorry I don't know how to isolate the code within these little comments boxes. Thanks again

Comment: `<a onClick="alert('Button Clicked!);" href="#">` should be `<a onClick="alert('Button Clicked!');" href="#">` : I missed a ' after the alert string

Comment: Oops! i found it.  the last single quote mark was missing at the end of the alert message 'Button Clicked!).  Thanks very much

Comment: @Trey:  Is there a way I can put the button image in the addcart class so that I can set it as a background image and have it show through? it appears to be behind the large image.  I'm trying z-index, but that is not working.  here is my css code: .addcart {
z-index: 30; 
margin: 25px 20px 80px 700px; 
width: 176px;
height: 48px;  
background:url(../images/addcart.jpg;
} '

Comment: which element are you adding the class to?

Comment: I would like to add it to the addcart class

Comment: .addcart {
z-index: 30; 
margin: 25px 20px 80px 700px; 
width: 176px;
height: 48px;  
background:url(../images/addcart.jpg;
}

Answer (score 0):

doable

you can hide the button under the image, could have some headache in positioning tho

Comment: Thanks, Trey.  I'm getting an error "unterminated string constant" could you tell me what that means?

Comment: @mick it means you haven't closed a quotation mark around a string somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but I had to wait 5 mins before I could post it :O